# Why does using execSQL() with a SQLiteCursorLoader produce an AsyncTask fatal exception?

Tags: android

I'm developing a dictionary app for Android and want to use the [CWAC LoaderEx library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) to handle the SQL grunt work. My loader initializes just fine (it populates a listView with the SQL statement I specified in onCreateLoader), but I can't figure out how to reset the loader to run another query with the user's search term.

I tried running **execSQL()** in **onQueryTextChange** to initiate a search on each character the user enters:

```
loader.execSQL(sqlStatement, new String[] { query + "%" });
```

But the app crashes with the following error:

```
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
* 03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1644)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLiteCursorLoader$ExecSQLTask.doInBackground(SQLiteCursorLoader.java:188)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.SQLiteCursorLoader$ExecSQLTask.doInBackground(SQLiteCursorLoader.java:1)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-04 12:10:36.310: E/AndroidRuntime(15293):    ... 4 more
```

According to the [LoaderEx docs](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex#database-modifications), I should be able to use execSQL in this manner to reuse an existing SQLiteCursorLoader. Did I misinterpret the documentation? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL statement apparently returns a result set. That is not allowed with `execSQL()` on a `SQLiteDatabase`. This has nothing to do with `SQLiteCursorLoader`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should have read the official Android docs more closely. Thanks for clearing that up.